# Send table checkbox value array via HTTP Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, http-post

I have this table with which I create dynamic checkboxes (the number of records may/will vary) the idea is that I can select a checkbox on whatever table row and "Send" those records.

I want to send an array of ID's off to a different page for processing - but i'm very stuck!

Here is my table/form code

```
<form action="processingpage.aspx" method="post">
  <asp:Repeater ID="GroupList" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
       <table id="grouptable" class="table"> 
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Broadcast</th>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Last Modified</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="BroadcastSelect[]" value="<%# Eval("Group_ID") %>"</input></td>
          <td><%# Eval("Group_ID") %></td>
          <td><%# Eval("DESC") %></td>
          <td><label id="test">hello</label></td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="<%# Eval("gURL") %>">Edit</a>/td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
         </tbody>
       </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
  <input class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Broadcast"/>
</form>
```

I think this is sending the array ok as I managed to see this via Request.in

`BroadcastSelect[]TESTGROUP`  (which is one of the items I sent)

but on my receiving page I'm getting nothing but blank text I've tried

```
Label1.Text = Page.Request.Form["BroadcastSelect[0]"];
```

and

```
Label1.Text = Page.Request.QueryString["BroadcastSelect[0]"];
```

but no values are printed. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your `<input>` is not correctly formatted, it is not being closed off correctly. Don't know if that will make any difference though

Comment: just spotted this myself, no difference though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that it is not possible to index the `<input name="BroadcastSelect[]">` through `Request.Form` or `Request.QueryString`.

If you breakpoint in the code, you will see that the Request.Form object will have `Request.Form["BroadcastSelect[]"]` as one of the available items, which will return a CSV list of values.

So try using this instead...

```
string broadcastSelect = Request.Form["BroadcastSelect[]"];
if (broadcastSelect != null)
{
   string[] broadcastSelectParts = broadcastSelect.Split(',');
   Label1.Text = broadcastSelectParts[0];
}
```

Obviously the code in the block can also be brought down to a single line, but if you want something other than the 1st item, check that you're not selected an "out of bound" index...

```
Label1.Text = broadcastSelect.Split(',')[0];
```

Comment: that seems to be coming through :)  is there any way to determine how many items are in the post?  thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: `broadcastSelectParts.Length`?  Obviously that would only work if there is a valid string to split, as an empty string split will produce one item. **EDIT** however, saying that, there is the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option that you can use on `Split`

Comment: @JazziJeff, or are you talking about the total number of posts in the entire `Request.Form`? That is more tricky, as you have to take into account the _EVENTTARGET type items, as well as the indexed items such as your input above

Comment: no i was talking about that specific element of the post - its been a long day , i forgot about .Length :)  thats enough to get me going though thanks again for the help!

Comment: You're welcome @JazziJeff - good luck with the rest of your project, and I hope (for your sake) that your day end soon :-)

Comment: You can use the method `Request.QueryString.GetValues("BroadcastSelect[]")` to get an array of values, you do not need to split the comma.